# Are the stored procedures parameters in a sys table? (Oracle)

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, oracle10g, meta, sys

I need some meta data about my stored procedures. I know oracle stores meta information of its objects in sys tables.

[systemtables](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e17114/systemtables.htm)

Does oracle store the parameter information of stored procedures?
Like name, type and maybe description?

---

SYS.ALL_STORED_SETTINGS
does not store this information. It only stores plsql meta parameter information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in the [ALL_ARGUMENTS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1014.htm#i1573843) view

Comment: I was searching for 'param' the whole time - not for arguments. Thx